# How to save an image to the internal memory

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a mobile app to do a screenshot at regular intervals. Then the image would be retrieved and sent by MMS.

My problem is that I work with a galaxy S6 edge with android 7.0 and therefore that has no memory card. The program runs on a kitkat phone with a memory card but does not work on the S6 Galaxy.

How can the image be stored in the internal memory?
What is the path to access the MMS application?

Thank you

Comment: did you add **run time permission** for **galaxy S6 edge with android 7.0**

Comment: For now I put a button that triggers the screenshot to verify that it works.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file give below permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Give runtime permissions in your java file:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_PERMISSION_CODE);
}
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, READ_PERMISSION_CODE);
}
```

Method for saving images to Internal memory/ SD card

(When you try to write to device's external memory, first the android tries to find the installed SD card on the device and writes to it. If, SD card is not available then the data gets written in device's internal memory:

```
    private void saveImageToLog(){
    String timeStampString = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    File appDirectory = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyAppImageLog" );
    File photo = new File(appDirectory, "photo_" + timeStampString+ ".png");

    if ( !appDirectory.exists() ) {
        appDirectory.mkdir();
    }

    if (photo.exists()) {
        photo.delete();
    }

    try {
        Bitmap bmp = bitmapImage;
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("log_tag", e.toString());
        testInvalid = "";
    }
}
```